# Accessing environment variable in chefSpec

Tags: chef-infra, chefspec

I am trying to write some test for my recipe using ChefSpec.

This is piece of code I am trying to test:

```ruby
file node[:storm][:job_dir] + node[:storm_work_gen][:jar_name] do
  owner node[:storm][:user]
  group node[:storm][:user]
  action :delete
  only_if { File.exist? node[:storm][:job_dir]+node[:storm_work_gen][:jar_name] }
end
```

Here the value of `node[:storm_work_gen][:jar_name]` is coming from a environment file. Content of my env file is:

```ruby
# coding: UTF-8

name 'sro_work_gen_dev'
description 'Sro Work Generator Environment for dev cluster'

override_attributes()

default_attributes(
    storm_work_gen: {
        cache_prop: {
            expire_time: '30',
            max_record_size: '100'
        },
        parallelism_hint: {
            kafka_spout_brq_sfq_ph: '1',
            kafka_spout_ftl_ph: '1',
            data_marshaller_ph: '1',
            data_processor_ph: '1',
            item_lookup_ph: '1',
            rule_applier_ph: '1',
            worlist_writer_ph: '1'
        },
        num_workers: '2',
        Topology_Name: 'WorkGen-tplgy-json-version',
        Kafka_Zookeepers: '...',
        Kafka_Broker: '...',
        repo_url: '...',
        jar_name: 'wlm-workgenerator-topology-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'
    }
)
```

And my spec looks like this:

```ruby
describe 'storm_wlm_deploy::_artifact' do

  # let(:chef_run) { ChefSpec::SoloRunner.new.converge(described_recipe) }
  let(:chef_run) do
    ChefSpec::SoloRunner.new do |node|
      env = Chef::Environment.new
      env.name 'storm_work_gen'
      allow(node).to receive(:chef_environment).and_return(env.name)
      allow(Chef::Environment).to receive(:load).and_return(env)
    end.converge(described_recipe)
  end

  it 'delete the jar:/opt/swlm/storm_jobs/wlm-workgenerator-topology-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar if it exists' do
    expect(chef_run).to delete_file('/opt/swlm/storm_jobs/wlm-workgenerator-topology-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar')
  end
end
```

The spec fails with message:

```
NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
at line file node[:storm][:job_dir] + node[:storm_work_gen][:jar_name] do
```

I want to know how to get node[:storm_work_gen][:jar_name] from the env file when chefSpec runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting up a mock environment, but you aren't actually telling Chef to use it for anything. Also you aren't putting any data in it. While it has the same name as the environment in your file, the two have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: After I mock, I am trying to understand as to how i can mock node[:storm_work_gen][:jar_name]  in the receipe when chefSpec runs, could you point out how I do this.

Comment: I would just set it directly in the node for the purposes of testing. Get rid of the env stub and add `node.set[:storm_work_gen][:jar_name] = 'whatever'` in that same block.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who were looking for this solution but, not clear on how to configure the node value based on the above comments here's a breakdown based on the above example:

Initially:

`describe 'storm_wlm_deploy::_artifact' do
    let(:chef_run) do
        ChefSpec::SoloRunner.new do |node|
            env = Chef::Environment.new
            env.name 'storm_work_gen'
            allow(node).to receive(:chef_environment).and_return(env.name)
            allow(Chef::Environment).to receive(:load).and_return(env)
        end.converge(described_recipe)
    end
    it 'delete the jar:/opt/swlm/storm_jobs/wlm-workgenerator-topology-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar if it exists' do
        expect(chef_run).to delete_file('/opt/swlm/storm_jobs/wlm-workgenerator-topology-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar')
    end
end`

Updated:

`describe 'storm_wlm_deploy::_artifact' do
    let(:chef_run) do
        ChefSpec::SoloRunner.new do |node|
            node.set[:storm_work_gen][:jar_name] = 'wlm-workgenerator-topology-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'
        end.converge(described_recipe)
    end
    it 'delete the jar:/opt/swlm/storm_jobs/wlm-workgenerator-topology-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar if it exists' do
        expect(chef_run).to delete_file('/opt/swlm/storm_jobs/wlm-workgenerator-topology-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar')
    end
end`